# Indexing an std::vector with a negative index

Tags: c++, type-conversion, implicit-conversion

I tried to index a `vector` using a negative index. The `vector::at()` member function  checks whether the specified index is within the bounds of the vector, and if this does not occur, an `out_of_range` exception is thrown.

```
vector<float> array;   // sample vector
array.push_back(0.123);
array.push_back(1.234);
array.push_back(2.345);
array.push_back(3.456);
array.push_back(4.567);

int index = -1;
float f = array.at(index);
cout << f << endl;
```

The signature of `vector::at()` member function requires that the specified parameter is of `vector<T>::size_type` type, and this type is `unsigned int` for the vector, so the compiler should perform an implicit conversion from `int` (the type of the `index` variable) to `unsigned int`. Since the `index` value is `-1` in the above example, the implicitly converted `index` is `4294967295` (that is the max value of the `unsigned int` type): this value is passed to `vector::at()` member function, which throws an `out_of_range` exception.

In other words, this exception is not thrown because the `vector::at()` member function sees that the `index` is less than zero, but rather because the implicitly converted `index` is greater than the current size of the `vector`. Is this a correct explanation?

Comment: Yes, that is the right explanation.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, that is a correct explanation.  (Except `at` takes a `vector::size_type`, usually `std::size_t`, which is some unspecified unsigned integer type (usually the bit-width of pointers on your system).  It being `unsigned int` on your system is allowed, but not mandated by the standard; 32 bit `unsigned int` with 64 bit `size_t` is common.)

As an aside, be careful with unsigned to signed conversion: the standard does not require it be a round-trip going signed->unsigned->signed for negative values, and some compilers *aggressively* optimize in unexpected ways.

Comment: What does it mean that _the standard does not require it be the inverse for negative values_?

Comment: `(int)(unsigned)-1 == -1` need not be true.

Comment: "some compilers aggressively optimize in unexpected ways" - this conversion is *implementation-defined* so there shouldn't be any optimization surprises

Comment: `at` takes a `std::vector::size_type`.

Comment: Actually, `at()` takes a `std::vector<float>::size_type`, which may but need not be the same as `std::size_t`.